# SPI loopback with DMA

Tags: embedded, stm32, spi, dma

Am using STM32F4 discovery board and I am attempting to get SPI loopback with DMA.
I have succesfully get an "SPI-only" loopback running, but now i want use DMA in addition with the SPI, here are the functions am using:

Initialisation of SPI [EDIT]

```
void init_SPI1(void){    
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStruct ;

  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_5|GPIO_Pin_4;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
  // connect SPI1 pins to SPI alternate function

  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource4, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_SPI1);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_SPI1);

  //Set chip select high 
  GPIOA->BSRRL |= GPIO_Pin_4; // set PA4 high

  // enable SPI1 peripheral clock
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);
  /* configure SPI1 in Mode 0 
   * CPOL = 0 --> clock is low when idle
   * CPHA = 0 --> data is sampled at the first edge*/
  SPI_StructInit(&SPI_InitStruct); // set default settings 
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex; // set to full duplex mode, seperate MOSI and MISO lines
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;     // transmit in master mode, NSS pin has to be always high
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b; // one packet of data is 8 bits wide
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;        // clock is low when idle
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_1Edge;      // data sampled at first edge
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft ; // set the NSS management to internal and pull internal NSS high
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_4; // SPI frequency is APB2 frequency / 4
  SPI_InitStruct.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;// data is transmitted MSB first
  SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStruct); 

  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = SPI1_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);  

  SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI1,SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);
  return;
}
```

Configuration of DMA [EDIT]:

```
void DMA_Config()
{  
DMA_InitTypeDef DMA_InitStructure;   
NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);

DMA_ClearFlag(DMA2_Stream5,        DMA_FLAG_FEIF2|DMA_FLAG_DMEIF2|DMA_FLAG_TEIF2|DMA_FLAG_HTIF2|DMA_FLAG_TCIF2);
DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream5, DISABLE);
while (DMA2_Stream5->CR & DMA_SxCR_EN);
DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Stream5);
DMA_StructInit(&DMA_InitStructure);

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_3;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr  = (uint32_t) &(SPI1->DR);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr  = (uint32_t) &spiTxBuff;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_MemoryToPeripheral;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize  = SPI_TX_MAX;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc  = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc  = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize  = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize  = DMA_MemoryDataSize_Byte;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode  = DMA_Mode_Normal;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority  = DMA_Priority_High;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOMode  = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable;

DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream5, &DMA_InitStructure); 

/**
configuration of the interrupts of DMA
******************************************************/
DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream5, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA2_Stream5_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 2;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);  
return;
}
```

SPI Write function:

```
void SPI1_Write(uint8_t *txBuff,int length,tSPI_Callback fct)
{
 DMA2_Stream5->M0AR = (uint32_t) &spiTxBuff;
 DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream5, ENABLE);
 SPI_I2S_DMACmd(SPI1, SPI_I2S_DMAReq_Tx, ENABLE);
 SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);
}
```

The data received are writen in the Rx Buffer using spi interrupt handler.

```
void SPI1_IRQHandler()
{
 spiRxBuff[spiRxCount] = SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPI1);
 spiRxCount++;
}
```

am calling these functions in the main as follow :

main.c:

```
DMA_Config();
init_SPI1();
SPI1_Write(spiTxBuff,SPI_TX_MAX,(void*)0);
```

Using a debugger i found that ,in the DMA high interrupt status register, TCIF5(Transfer Complete Flag) and HTIF5(Half Transfer complete Flag) are set to 1 means that transfer is done successfully in my opinion, however i didn't get any data in the SPI Rx Buffer, the second strange thing is that neither DMA Interrupt nor SPI Interrupt is triggered. Could you please help me figure out what is wrong in my code.

**EDIT**

The DMA and SPI interrupts are triggered but the problem am getting now is that i can't receive all the elements, i can just receive the first one

```
uint8_t spiTxBuff[SPI_TX_MAX] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,0x08,0x09,0x10};
```

but `spiRxBuff[SPI_RX_MAX] ={0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}`

Did that problem come from the fact that DMA is faster than the interrupt handler and so SPI interrupt handler didn't have the time to handle all the received data ?

Comment: There is one reference to `DMA1` in your code.  Should that be `DMA2`?

Comment: yes you're right thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As kkrambo has pointed it out, you're enabling the interrupt for DMA1 instead of DMA2. Don't forget to install an interrupt handler there.
- What's the stuff with DMA2_Stream2?
- SPI interrupt is apparently not configured (or I can't find where). Like:
  `SPI_I2S_ITConfig(SPI1,SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);`

Comment: Thank you @berendi, now i get the SPI and DMA interrupts triggered, but still a probleme to fix, in fact i can't receive all the data sent by the DMA.does that problem due to the fact that DMA is faster than SPI Interrupt handler, i mean SPI Interrupt Handler didn't have the time to handle all tha data ?

Comment: @fedi - is it really all that surprising that you can send data out on SPI via DMA faster than you can read it in with per-byte interrupts?   Try setting up SPI_BaudRatePrescaler to run significantly slower.  If this fixes the problem, then you are *probably* just "overflowing" on the input side.  If not, you may have other problems.

Comment: @Brian McFarland, you mean there is no relation with the problem am getting and the DMA transfer frequency ?  it can be not a very good remark from my side, but this is what i thought in a first side,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you didn't read received byte inside SPI ISR, if you do so this will lead to DMA won't find bytes to be copied.
I mean, DMA and SPI are two resources trying to read the same buffer, you don't know which one of them will get the byte first.
Also, DMA works while still SPI ISR  Flag raised, if SPI read the byte this flag will be cleared which lead to DMA won't work.